# What type of wavelength is the light from a lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber

There are different types of light on the spectrum as many of you science geeks will know. These are made up of different frequencies and wavelengths. My question is this:

**Is there an ACTUAL light on the spectrum that can be visible, cut things and reflect its self just as a lightsaber does and if so what light is it?**

I don't care if the answer is canon or not. 
**I'm just wondering if this has ever been explained throughout the Star Wars universe.**

I am not looking for a lightsaber tutorial, unless that explains what wave length the light is.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be the same place on the spectrum as the visible color of the light saber? If not, where is the red light we see with our eyes when we look at Darth Vader's light saber (for example) coming from? Light sabers are also sometimes called "laser swords", and the light used in a real-life laser always matches the color of the dot it makes (or the color of the beam if there are particles in the air to reflect it)

Comment: But then how could it cut/reflect things?

Comment: Well, real lasers in the visible spectrum can cut things by heating them if they have enough intensity (intensity is energy delivered per unit time). But light sabers aren't supposed to be just lasers, but some kind of superheated [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) contained within a force field, see the [lightsaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber) article on Wookieepedia.

Comment: Based on your comment, it doesn't look like you want to ask what you've asked, it looks like you want a basic tutorial on lightsaber operation

Comment: Your edit has actually taken the question fully off topic and is now requesting a scientific explanation.

Comment: Ok people I want an answer. Quit sapping my reputation and just tell me yes or no.

Comment: @JacksonWalker - The problem here is that you're evidently looking for a scientific explanation for a weapon that it wholly based in fiction. On top of that, your question utterly ignores the fact that within the fictional universe, a lightsaber isn't actually made up of light at all, it's actually highly energetic plasma contained within a strong tube-shaped magnetic field.

Comment: THERE! THATS WHAT IS NEEDED PUT THAT AS AN ANSWER
 ILL UPVOTE

Comment: Revisiting and old question … Have you considered posting a similar one to physics.stackexchange.com or even worldbuilding.stackexchange.com sites?

Answer (score 8):

Canonically, the lightsaber is given its color by the [kyber crystal](http://www.starwars.com/databank/lightsaber-crystal) used in its construction. A crystal is initially

> colorless until first attuned and connected to a Jedi -- at which times it glows either blue or green, or in some rare instances, another shade. From that point on, it retains that hue.

Since the crystal *glows* a certain color, the implication is that the crystal emits light, and since the light is visible it must fall in the visible spectrum.

The Sith use [synthetic crystals](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_crystal/Canon) which give them a red color, but the mechanism is the same.

In Legends, the color of a lightsaber can be affected by a [color crystal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal#Known_color_crystals), presumably by the same mechanism. The color could be all or partially black, which would presumably be caused by light emitted from a non-visible spectrum like ultraviolet (but that spectrum is unknown).

Answer (score -1):

Technically the blade is Plasma according to the lore... doesnt make a lot of sense, but there it is.

Okay... in the book "Star Wars Rebels: the visual Guide" the blade of the lightsaber is first canonically referred to as a Plasma blade.

Since then other canon sources have referred to it as a plasma blade. This appears to be exclusive to the New Canon though and not the previous expanded universe.

The sources do not elaborate or expound upon this, the blade is simply referred to as plasma and that is the end of it. No explanation is given as to how it is possible, or how it works.

Comment: Could you cite some passage or source for this information?

Comment: Yes please. I need a bit more info.

Comment: Okay... in the book "Star Wars Rebels: the visual Guide" the blade of the lightsaber is first canonically referred to as a Plasma blade.

Since then other canon sources have referred to it as a plasma blade. This appears to be exclusive to the New Canon though and not the previous expanded universe.